# Electron balance for biomass synthesis: is my professor right?

Tags: biochemistry

I'm studying for my exam and I came across these notes written by the professor himself. He's talking about the general reaction of biomass production in a bioreactor:

$$\ce{C6H12O6 + NH4+ + O2 -> $\mathrm{C_wH_xO_yN_z}$ + CO2 + H2O + H+}
\\\text{(not balanced)}$$

At some point he proceeds to do the "reduction balance" for this reaction: he calculates the "reduction degree" of the elements (which he defines the same way I define the oxidation number) and here comes the problem.

He states the "reduction degree" of **C** in glucose is +4 and the one of **O** in **O<sub>2</sub>** is -2.

Is "reduction degree" different from oxidation number? Are there any particular ways to calculate oxidation numbers when you talk about biomass?

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 1):

The terms are different.
Oxidation number is the difference in number of electrons (not pairs) from the elemental form (which for many elements exists only on paper) of an atom.
Degree of reduction is a more uncommon term that is basically the number of electrons that atoms in a molecule are donating per atoms of a given element. It is calculated formally by summing the number of electrons donated to reach a full shell (H=1, C=4, N=-3, O=-2, P=5, S=6 etc.) divided by the number of a given element, but that is more confusing than anything.
Carbon can be oxidised four times, *e.g.* methane > methanol > formaldehyde > formate > carbon dioxide (not biological route, just an example), while oxygen can be reduced twice: to hydrogen peroxide and then to water. As proof, most O2 dependent enzymes produce hydrogen peroxide (*e.g.* FADH2 enzymes). That is a cheat way to work out where those numbers come from.
I would recommend forgetting about the formal calculations of oxidation numbers —in biology oxidation numbers of carbon are generally not discussed.
I will open the brief parenthesis of the oxidation states of carbon just to point out they are not those: -1 for a bond with hydrogen, +1 with oxygen and 0 for a C-C bond. Carbon monoxide therefore has an oxidation state of +4, while a C in glucose (on average) has a -1. Molecular oxygen has two identical atoms therefore is 0. Elemental carbon has 6 electrons so hypothetically you cannot strip carbon more than +6. 
Here what is important is figuring out how many times a carbon in a molecule can be oxidised, that is how many electron pairs a molecule can give away as every time that happens an NAD+ (catabolism) or NADP+ (anabolism) is reduced, which is key to the cell. A dehydratase removes a hydroxyl group leaving an alkene, but it does not carry out a redox reaction: the geometry is no longer sp3, but sp2, and the oxidation state has decrease by 1 in that carbon, yet carbon kept its electrons —the other carbon increased by 1 as it deprotonated, so no net change and NADH is not generated.
Knowing how many electron pairs are given away going from glucose to carbon dioxide is important because cells cannot make them disappear and a terminal electron acceptor is needed either in the form of respiration or fermentation. There is a further concept, that of reduction potential. Different forms of terminal electron acceptors are employed in Nature: oxygen, Fe(III), sulfate etc. and these have different "energy" levels at which they accept the electrons (reduction potential, measured in volts), which translated to different amounts of energy that can be syphoned off during the reaction.

Comment: I don't think you answered the question --- what is "reduction degree", and is it different from oxidation number / oxidation state? You mention "redox potential", by this do you mean "reduction degree"?

Comment: Sorry, you are right. I edited my answer.

Comment: Thanks, it is improving!  Can you provide some references on "degree of reduction" ?  This seems like a pretty obscure concept --- I teach cell biology / biochemistry but I have never heard about this, and I have a hard time finding anything.

Comment: Sorry, after staring at this for some time, I still don't get your definition of "degree of reduction". What do you mean by "divided by the *number* of a given element" ?  Atom number?  Stoichiometry coefficient?  As I understand it, you should *multiply* the atom valence by the stoichiometry coefficient ?

Comment: I also didn't quite get how you determine the reduction degree..
For example: I can follow you when you talk about different oxidation states of carbon, but still I don't get: what is the reduction degree of carbon in glucose and carbon dioxide?

Comment: The crux of what I tried to say is to not concentrate on the maths and to focus on the concept that the more the carbon is bonded with oxygen and less with hydrogen, the more electron pairs the molecule gives away (= oxidised). Hydrogen is happy as a proton, not a hydride. If the latter were true all of this would be meaningless. Instead you have to have NADH carrying the hydride (and the energy with it).